# Is $f(x,y) = \dfrac{y+2}{x+y+2}$ convex anywhere? This is driving me crazy.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

So, from Multivariate Calculus and Linear Algebra, I learned that:

1. Given $f(x,y)$, I can find out if it is convex by checking if the eigenvalues of its Hessian are positive or zero (i.e. if the Hessian is positive-semidefinite).
2. The determinant of any matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

Therefore, I assumed that, given a simple function $f(x,y) = \frac{y+2}{x+y+2}$, which looks convex in the positive domain (picture below), I could just find its Hessian, take the derivative and note that it was not negative in this region (positive $x, y$). I know that being positive could mean it is either convex or concave, but I was hoping not to see a negative determinant in this region.

[image]

Its Hessian is easy to compute:

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2(y+2)}{(x+y+2)^3} & \frac{-x+y+2}{(x+y+2)^3} \\ 
\frac{-x+y+2}{(x+y+2)^3} & \frac{-2x}{(x+y+2)^3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant, though, is negative everywhere, independent of $x, y$. That is:

$$\det(H) = \frac{-1}{(x+y+2)^4} < 0$$ everywhere.

Now, following from (1) and (2), this would mean that even for $x, y>0$, the region where it is apparently convex, both eigenvalues of H have opposite signs, which would make H not positive-semidefinite, which would make $f(x,y)$ not convex anywhere. This simply does not seem to be the case by just graphing the function.

What did I get wrong?

PS: I know it is concave for most of the negative region and that f is not convex in $\Bbb R^2$. I just wanted to 'prove' that it is convex for positive $x, y$.

Comment: It is a problem of resolution. This is the plot when it is done with [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3d+plot&assumption=%7B%22MC%22%2C+%223d+plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%2C+%22dflt%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%223DPlot%22%2C+%223dplotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28y%2B2%29%2F%28x%2By%2B2%29%22)

Comment: Nothing wrong. The Hessian matrix has signature $(n_0,n_+,n_-)=(0,1,1)$ at all points of the domain (not just the "positive region"), and the function is nowhere convex and nowhere concave.

Comment: I think It Is convex on the positives on lines as t(v,z) + (0,0) so the cut seems convex, but It Is not convex on lines as t(c,c) + (c,0) for example for some c values.

Comment: @Marco Good point for Wolfram Alpha. But it is much more a *domain problem* than a "resolution problem" (resolution = grid fineness)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph does not have a positive-definite nor negative-definite hessian anywhere; it is not convex on any open region. One nice way of seeing this is to restrict the function, at any point $(x_0, y_0) \in (0, \infty)^2$ to two different lines passing through the point, and verify that the function is convex in one direction, but concave in the other. That is, as your calculation verifies, each point is a saddle point.

It's not difficult to do. Fix $(x_0, y_0)$, and consider:
$$g(x) = f(x, y_0) = \frac{y_0 + 2}{x + y_0 + 2},$$
which has second derivative:
$$g''(x) = \frac{2(y_0 + 2)}{(x + y_0 + 2)^3} > 0,$$
hence the function is convex in this direction, i.e. along the horizontal line $y = y_0$. On the other hand, if we let:
$$h(y) = f(x_0, y) = \frac{y + 2}{x_0 + y + 2} = 1 - \frac{x_0}{x_0 + y + 2},$$
then
$$h''(y) = -\frac{2x_0}{(x_0 + y + 2)^3} < 0,$$
so the function is concave in the vertical direction $x = x_0$.

Comment: It makes sense! Thank you for the explanation! I was too focused on the 3d-plot and trying to find out what I got wrong in my calculations.

Comment: but then $h''(y)$ would be positive if, for instance, $x_0=-0.1$ and $y=10$ right? $h''(10) = \frac{- 2(-0.1)}{(-0.1 + 10 + 2)^3} = \frac{0.2}{11.9^3} = 0.00011868316$. Does this mean that there is another direction that is not parallel to x or y axis where the function would be concave? because for this exact point, both 2nd derivatives are > 0.

Comment: I assumed you were looking only at $x_0, y_0 > 0$. But yes, this would be the case. It would be sensible to check the eigenvectors of the Hessian matrix; one will correspond to a negative eigenvalue, and one to a positive eigenvalue (and should be orthogonal). Along these eigenspaces, the function will be concave and convex respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Yes, originally I was indeed looking at positive values for both, but now I became interested in finding out if it is convex anywhere. On you answer, you mentioned that 'every point is a saddle point', and I'm struggling a little bit with this, because the graph for negative x close to 0 really seem to be convex in both directions

Comment: @William Your determinant calculation says that it's not convex anywhere. Given the function is twice differentiable on its domain, you'd need a positive-definite Hessian, which requires a positive determinant. The determinant is never positive.

Comment: I think I'll just trust the arithmetic. I mean, for all values where the 3d-plot looks convex, I get a positive and a negative eigenvalue, as you predicted (and as the negative determinant also predicts). I just wanted to 'see' the concavity on the plot. For positive values, I can see it now, The graph 'arches' slightly on the y direction. But for -1 < x < 0, it still does not look that way. But yeah, I don't think it's worth it taking more time on this. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me. I wish you a great weekend!